# CF_RETURNS_RETAINED or CF_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED: which to use when?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, swift, core-foundation

I am unsure whether to use CF_RETURNS_RETAINED or CF_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED for my custom function returning a `CFDataProviderRef`.

According to [the documentation at the location where the macros are defined](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFBase.h), both should only used in exceptional circumstances, and the correct fix should be to fix my naming convention.
However The swift/objective-c documentation [suggests using](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_50) them to annotate any function returning a CoreFoundation pointer, without really explaining when to use which --- if I don't annotate them I need to manually specify the behaviour every time in the swift code.

Further documentation I could find explains how one uses a ARC value of +1 and the other of 0, however I'm afraid that doesn't help me much in understanding.

My questions:

1. Should I be using them at all, or improve my naming as `Base.h` suggests?
2. What is the exact naming convention that is being used there?
3. Am I correct in assuming that I should use one if I want the memory used by the returned object free'd as soon as it goes out of scope in the caller, and the other if I don't want this to happen (because I use a pointer to it somewhere else, or clean up myself)?
4. All my function does is return a `CFDataProviderRef` that I got from a call to `CGDataProviderCreateSequential`. I guess that means I want the the behaviour as `CGDataProviderCreateSequential` (right?). How can I find whether that function uses CF_RETURNS_RETAINED or CF_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED (it's not there in the `CGDataProvider.h` file)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is all about ownership. The naming convention is that of Core Foundation, which is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029). The Create Rule says that functions with "Create" and "Copy" in their name leave the caller with ownership of the returned object (although not necessarily *sole* ownership). That means that the caller has a responsibility to eventually release the returned object using `CFRelease()`. The Get Rule says that functions other than creation or copy functions do not give the caller ownership of the object, so the caller must not call `CFRelease()` on it (except to balance any explicit calls to `CFRetain()`, of course).

If a function is semantically a creation or copy function which returns ownership to the caller, but its name doesn't indicate that, you should use `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED` to indicate that. Similarly, if a function's name contains "Create" or "Copy" but it doesn't have semantics matching the Create Rule, you should use `CF_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED` to indicate that. (Try to avoid this.)

Since your code is calling `CGDataProviderCreateSequential()` and since that has "Create" in the name, your code is responsible for releasing the returned `CGDataProvider` object. If you release it right there in your function, then your caller can't get access to it. You want to return the object to the caller. You also want to pass the responsibility for releasing the object to the caller, since you don't know when the caller will be done with it. So, you should name your function with "Create" in its name to indicate both to the caller and to automated systems that the caller receives responsibility for releasing the object. Alternatively, you could annotate your function with `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED` to signify that, but following the naming convention is better.

It's possible that Swift only respects the naming convention for system headers. I don't know. In that case, you'd have to annotate with `CF_RETURNS_RETAINED` even if your function has "Create" in its name. There's no harm in annotating a function whose name already follows the convention. It's redundant but harmless.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer, exactly what I was looking for. Any chance you can comment on the naming itself? CF_RETURNS_RETAINED seems to suggest that the called function retains a pointer to the object, however as you explain it (and possibly the source of my initial confusion) it's exactly the other way around (CF_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED retains a pointer in the called function). So probably I should think of these in another way...
I can confirm that (the current version of) swift does not use the naming convention for my custom function `CGDataProviderCreateFileHandle`.

Comment: I agree the names aren't great. Conceptually, you use `CFRelease()` to balance a retain. So, a function that returns something you need to release is returning something that has been retained on your behalf in that sense. By the way, don't name your own function `CGDataProviderCreateFileHandle()`. That makes it seem like it's a framework function. Use some prefix other than "CG". (It also makes it seem like you're requesting creation of a file handle. You might want to put "With" in there.)

Comment: Small correction: The "The Get Rule" applies (if I understand it correctly) to all functions that have *not* "Create" or "Copy" in their name. It is not required that they have "Get" in the name. There is no "not conforming to the naming convention" case.

Comment: @MartinR while that was initially correct, they appear to have made it more explicit with the advent of ARC and/or swift.  Swift now has three cases for handling C return results, owned, unowned, and unknown.  If it were still true that get wasn't required, then there would be no case where swift couldn't figure it out and had to fall back to using whatever the wrapper it uses around unknown retain cases is.  Sorry I'm not more specific, not in a place I can look it up easily.

Comment: @David: My comment was related to the "Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation" where you have only two cases: Either "Create Rule" or "Get Rule" (and I do not think that changed with ARC). I might be wrong but I do not think there is any documentation that mentions functions *"with "Get" in their name"*.

Comment: @MartinR: not really disagreeing with you.  I'm just pointing out that apparently at some point they've added a 3rd "unknown" case, otherwise the macros wouldn't be required and the Unmanaged<T> enum wouldn't need to exist.  For what it's worth, the macros came into existence with ARC.  The example Apple gives in the interchange document is that `StringByAddingTwoStrings` will be flagged as Unmanaged, when the prior Copy/Create rule would flag it as Nonretained.  Something changed sometime, and it doesn't seem like it's a fully documented change :)